# Datetime to date only in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

i have a date time like this

```
2012-01-01 10:00:00
```

i need to convert it into date only like this

```
2012-01-01
```

Can anyone help me please
 this is my code

```
NSDate *adate           =   objIStruct_Conference.m_DtDate;
        NSLog(@"DATE========%@",objIStruct_Conference.m_DtDate);
        NSString *DateString    =   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", adate ];

        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MM:dd"];
        NSLog(@"NEW DATE====%@", [formatter stringFromDate:adate]);
        [formatter release];
```

i am getting DATE===== 2012-01-01 10:00:00 , NEW DATE=====(null)

Comment: can you log for me the values of `adate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MM:dd"];
 NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
 [formatter release];
```

See the Class Reference of [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Are you getting the correct value while printing the NSLog(@"%@",adate); ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems your `adate` pointer would be `nil`, because it is working perfectly for me **on the real device** with a valid `NSDate` but when I set the `_date` to nil, the output will be `nil` as in your case.

```
NSDate *_date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[_dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSLog(@"%@", [_dateFormatter stringFromDate:_date]);
```

the output is:

```
2012-08-08
```